# difference between two for loops in C?

Tags: c

what is the difference between

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("Hello");
```

and

```
for(i=0;i<n;) printf("Hello");
```

I have seen the two types of code used in multiple places and could not figure out the difference.

Comment: your second loop is infinite since you are not changing the value of i

Comment: @Manoj, or did you mean `for( ;i<n; i++) printf("Hello");`

Answer (score 3):

The only difference I see is the "i++" part.  That increments i in the first loop, but it doesn't increment in the second loop.  Unless n<=0, the second loop will never end.  This is called an **infinite loop**.

I'd highly recommend reading more on loops with C:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_loops.htm

http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-for-loop-while-loop-break-and-continue

Answer (score 1):

The second one doesn't have a post-loop afterthought.  It's optional, but most of the time you update the index there.

Answer (score 0):

The one without i++ runs forever. There's nothing to increment it to reach it's final condition.

Answer (score 0):

The second code does not have an `i++`. This means it does not alter the index variable `i` during iterations.

The first line

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("Hello");
```

Can be translated to

```
int i=0;
while(i<n)
{
 printf("Hello");
 i++;
}
```

While the second

```
for(i=0;i<n;) printf("Hello");
```

would translate to

```
int i=0;
while (i<n)
{
 printf("Hello");
}
```

Since `i` does not change, it will loop infinitely

Answer (score 0):

`for(i=0;i<n;) printf("Hello");` this code will never terminate unless you explicitly modify your `i` in the body of your loop.

```
for(i=0;i<n;){
i++;
printf("Hello");
}
```

will be a valid ever terminated loop.